# Applying regex to Java8 List<String>

Tags: regex, java-8

I have an array list

`List<String> items = Arrays.asList("date=2017-01-10", "date=2017-02-10");`

I want to convert this list and have quotes for each item in the list so 
 `date=2017-01-10` can be converted to `date='2017-01-10'`

`List<String> items = Arrays.asList("date='2017-01-10'", "date='2017-02-10'");`

How can i do in Java 8 ?

UPDATE: I want to use regex to achieve this.

Comment: To do it in Java 8, try first doing it in Java 7 with regex, and then... leave it as is, because Java8 doesn't bring anything new to this table other than minor quality of life improvements.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, Streams?

Comment: @Clijsters, the definition of "quality of life improvement" for this task. There's nothing you can achieve with Stream that you couldn't achieve with Java7-style code.

Comment: Sure, I'd however tell it bad style, not use java8-style code in a java-8 code environment.

Comment: @Clijsters, The bad style in my opinion is trying to shoe-horn lambdas and streams literally everywhere, regardless of how they look and behave. For example, a Stream creates way more garbage than side-effectful `forEach`, and the actual `for-each` Java7-style creates almost no garbage.

Comment: Sure, but the OP asked for a Java-8-way solution, didn't he? Even if I agree with your statement, I doubt the garbage offset really matters in performance or anything really measurable. However, I didn't want to contradict you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen your profile, I found you start to Java. so I'll give you the answer just for learning purpose.

- use [lookbehind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) to skip replacement. e.g: `(?<==)`
- use [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) to capture the matched result in group, e.g: `(.+)`
- use `$` sign to references to captured group, e.g: `$1`.

  ```
  List<String> result = items.stream()
  //                                 match `=`            ---v
                             .map(it -> it.replaceFirst("(?<==)(.+)", "'$1'"))
  //                     capture the rest substring in group  ---^
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

You also can simply to use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) to achieve your way. for example:

```
int prefix = "date=".length();
List<String> result =items.stream()
                          .map(it->String.format("date='%s'",it.substring(prefix)))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceAll` with this regex `^(.*?)=(.*?)$` which return two groups one before the `=` the second after, so you can replace the input with group 1 `$1` followed by `='` then group 2 between two quotes `'$2'`:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("date=2017-01-10", "date=2017-02-10");
items = items.stream()
        .map(t -> t.replaceAll("(.*?)=(.*?)$", "$1='$2'"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

items.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Outputs**

```
date='2017-01-10'
date='2017-02-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

```
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("date=2017-01-10", "date=2017-02-10"), result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String item : items){
        item = item.replace("date=", "date='");
        item = item + "'";
        result.add(item);
    }
    for(String item : result){
        System.out.println(item);
    }
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/yOfTLe)